# How to parent mesh to bone?

Tags: import, parent

My model has bones and some of meshes are child of bone. When I import this model, such bone-mesh relationship is broken. Is there any way to import properly or fix these deparenting?

I can use weight painting for restore parent-child relationship but how can I restore transform of mesh?

I'm using blender 2.79.

[image]
(in blender)
[image]
(in 3Dmax)

Comment: Importing from or too blender? With what format?

Comment: @Sazerac Importing fbx file to blender. Above 3D max image is desired importing result. (`shield_container` contains `shield`)

Comment: what is your configuration to export, maybe you're misbehaving everything and that's why it breaks